# "You can't start a database activity stream in this configuration error" while starting database activity stream

Tags: amazon-rds, amazon-aurora, activity-streams

Getting this error `You can't start a database activity stream in this configuration. (Service: AmazonRDS; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidParameterCombination; Request ID: xxxxxx-xxxx-xxx-xxxx-xxxxxx; Proxy: null)` while starting database activity stream for AWS Aurora PostgreSQL database. Error is thrown on clicking continue in the `Start database activity stream` menu.
How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are setting some invalid parameters and/or parameter values.  (Likely, some parameters are incompatible with others)

Can you confirm which settings / parameters you are using when trying this operation?

Suggestions:

1. Check the request in the browser's javascript console.. does it have a JSON structure that can be inspected, and verified using the reference docs?
2. Instead of using the web-based admin page, can you try this operation using aws-cli, or otherwise using the API?  (With the intent of isolating the parameters that you're using)

Answer (score 0):

I found that for Aurora PostgreSQL database, the activity stream is supported only on r6g, r5, r4, and x2g instance classes.

For Aurora MySQL, the activity stream is supported on r6g, r5, r4, r3, and x2g instance classes.

I configured my DB with m2 instance class, when I changed that, I was able to start database activity stream.

More details can be found here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/DBActivityStreams.Overview.html